# XMLHttpRequest status is 0

Tags: java, javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am using `window.XMLHttpRequest`. The line commands are below.

The problem is that it is returning `status = 0`. I checked the url but it is right. What am I doing wrong?

```
var url = "http://177.55.99.146:8080/autenticacao/autentica?arquivo=" + file; 
req.open("Get", url, true); 
req.send(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this is caused by a cross-domain request (I assume your request is cross-domain since you specified the full url). Did you use the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header at http://177.55.99.146:8080/autenticacao/autentica?

Like this:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.allowed-domain.com");
?>
```